# How to put a LazyVerticalGrid item in a container?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, lazyvgrid

I have this composable fun:

```
LazyVerticalGrid(
               columns = GridCells.Fixed(3),
           ) {

               item (span = { GridItemSpan(3) }){
                   Header(
                       user,
                       sheetStateSettings
                   ) { newValue ->
                       isSheetOpened = newValue
                   }
               }

               itemsIndexed(listOfSenses) { index, item ->
                   FeedItem(item) {
                       profileViewModel.currentUserSelectedFeedItem.value = index
                       navHostController.navigate(ProfileGraphConstants.USER_FEED_SCREEN)
                   }
               }
           }
```

and it looks like this: [image]

and how I want it to look:[image: required]

I definitely need a lazy list, because when I scroll through this feed, more images are loaded from the server.
And the entire page should scroll, not just the list item on the page, that’s why I made the header as a list item